# Web app for client to alter 3D renders

Tags: web-apps, 3d

I'm trying to see if there's a web app that already exists before we go through the process of making one.

I'm looking for a way to create a render of an environment and be able to have the client click on a specific object in it (walls, a table, etc.) and change to color of it, or even swap out for a different texture. The purpose of this would be to speed up the process of the client giving notes on a design, and give them a little more creative control.

Again, I'm not sure if something like this already exists or not, and have had no luck searching on my own. If anyone knows of something like this, I'd greatly appreciate any information you could give me.

---

It wouldn't need to be something this large scale in 3D, it could be a 2D image with predetermined objects in it that the client could click on and a color wheel of sorts would pop up, and they could modify that object slightly. Something more along those lines.

Comment: Are you fine with solutions for self-hosting, or does it have to be hosted? Budget, or does it have to be gratis?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing that's available that I can think of would be the [three.js editor](http://threejs.org/editor/). It's [open source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/editor) so you could host a version yourself that points to the models you want, otherwise you'd have to tell your client to open it up, modify it, and send it back to you.

I know of a company that does this in the automotive sector for very high fidelity advertising stuff. Their name is [Mackevision](http://www.mackevision.com/) if you wanted to work with another company to look for a solution using the stuff they've already created.